# Harvey-Newbold test (2000) in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, out-of-sample, nested-models

I want to estimate the best nested model out-of sample and for that purpose, I will implement Harvey-Newbold test. However, I cannot find the respective test in any package.
Can anyone help me?
If this test is not implemented yet, do you have any alternative that meets the goal of estimating the best nested model out-of sample and is possible to implement in r?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The test you mention is implemented in this package: https://rdrr.io/cran/fDMA/man/mdmtest.html
Which is a wrapper around a test in the `forecast` R package.

Comment: I suspect that the test suggested there does not work for nested models as it is a refinement from Diebold-Mariano test which only works for non-nested models. From what I read only the 2020 paper of Harvey and Newbold works fine for nested models. Can you confirm this? Thanks